# Add buttons to sub-grid view

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-365

On the order form, there is a products section that has uses the default `Order Product Inline Edit View`. This view is not editable, but you can copy it and save it as a different name.

However, when you copy the view, the new view does not display all of the same buttons when viewing the sub-grid.

default view:

[image: The default sub-grid view buttons]

copied view (the lock pricing, move up and move down buttons are missing):

[image]

The copied view shows the `+` button and it's drop down menu correctly. Why hasn't it copied the other buttons, and how can i get them to show on my custom view?

I am happy to edit xml and upload that back to CRM if necessary.

Update:
FYI, this is all a pointless effort as the word template ignores the sequence order. What an utter waste of time.

Comment: Are the image in the correct order? I'm a little confused "the new view does not display all of the same buttons" but the image shows it with buttons. Which buttons are missing?

Comment: @JamesWood the lock pricing, move up and move down buttons are missing.

Comment: Tried to copy a view and check both copies out, there doesn't seem to be any particular difference in the savedquery XML nodes

Comment: @Alex this applies specifically to the products sub-grids (opportunity product, order product, invoice product). You can't customise the default view which includes the move-up/down buttons, and when you copy it they disappear.

Comment: @NickDewitt I know that, I copied the inline edit view to compare the original with a copy. I concur with James Wood answer, it's very likely that some "magic" is involved with the "default" view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to guess it's because the default view on the order of order products is a special one. It has special behaviours that arn't seen in the rest of 365, i.e. you don't get up, down, or lock on other views.

I would assume that the extra buttons only get shown on that default view and arn't really supported outside of that view.

Comment: yeah the default view is managed, and not editable. Yeah i know, all i want to do is show a product id column, and change the description width, i'm not taking away anything it needs to function from the view. It's so frustrating! There must be a way, i just need to find the relevant javascript library and hook a button up to it, i'll find something.

Comment: @NickDewitt, there doesnt have to be a way to do anything, related reading: https://woodsworkblog.wordpress.com/2017/06/25/microsoft-dynamics-365-and-the-importance-of-staying-supported/

Comment: yeah i know, i could always write a chrome extension to insert the relevant html into the page but i would have to update it every time. i would rather hook a button to the same function they have those `MoveUp` and `MoveDown` functions attached to and then it would probably last longer. I just find it frustrating that it's dynamic by name but static by nature once you try to do simple customisations (changing column widths) on core elements.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it is actually quite easy to show these buttons for other views using the ribbon workbench.

1. Right click on the button in ribbon workbench under the subgrid section and click on customise
2. Select the command in the "solution elements" pane at the bottom
3. In the bottom right hand pane, right click on the enable rule "Mscrm.IsInlineEditView" and click "Remove from Command"
4. Publish

These buttons now show up for all views.